# irc server and web irc-client for debian

Tags: debian, irc

I need irc server and irc client with browser interface.
Os is Debian.

irc server will be used mostly locally and there can be about a dozen remote clients.

irc client must be accessible with browser, preferably without Flash/Java plugins.

Both must be debian packets.

The link to good tutorial would be wonderful.

The security needed: minimal is only password protection to access irc-client (web folder password). maximum - access to irc room only by registered and "approved" users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [ircd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRCd) before, and it worked pretty well and was easy to set up.  You should already have it in your APT repository for [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/sid/ircd-hybrid).  Also, [here's](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/ircd/ircopguide.html) a pretty good page on running an IRC server.

As for the client, there's probably several out there, but one I found is [CGI:IRC](http://cgiirc.org/).

Comment: cgiirc is the name of the debian package.

Comment: and what name of good ircd package?

Comment: I have a link there to ircd-hybrid in my answer, which is a debian package.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run everything yourself i run this setup on my own servers, with a regular user account.

1. [Unreal](http://www.unrealircd.com/) for IRC  - its well tested, and not too hard to set up- just read and understand the config files . they need to be downloaded and compiled, and run as a regular user, and started up with crontab.
2. [Anope](http://www.anope.org/) for services - You need services - it allows for channel ops, admins, and channel protection. You'd prolly need to look up the link block for it in the docs
3. <strike>[Qwebirc](http://qwebirc.org/) if you want to have a good *modern* irc web client you run yourself. Requires a reasonably recent version of python, so if you run stable or oldstable you might need to check.Its relatively new but quakenet, and freenode use it.</strike>. My preferences have since changed, and I'd recommend kiwiirc instead. This needs node.js, so a distro with a up to date official/community repository would be awesome

They arn't packaged but this is a stable, well tested, and utterly reliable combination of apps

Comment: irc soft for APT repository is easier for me to setup.

Answer (score 1):

Second the vote for ircd for pretty simple setup for a smaller group.

http://www.mibbit.com/ webchat is a good browser client although it may use Javascript.  It can be used on an iPhone.

Comment: no, i need chat for intranet.